# Dojo query error: TypeError: query(...).forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, dojo

I have multiple classes in my HTML named ".slider" and I want to use dojo query to get these classes so that I can do a .forEach on each node.

This is what I had:

```
 query('.slider').forEach(function(node){
       do something
    })
```

For some reasons it keeps saying that TypeError: query(...).forEach is not a function.

When I consolelogged my query('.slider'), I was expecting a node list but what showed on the browser was like:
[image]

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-checked the dojo.query documentation and it looks like I need to use dojo.query instead of .query because I am on a lower version